# Understanding verb+の+verb/adjective

Tags: grammar, omission

A group of girls go on a trip and now they are sleeping in their rooms in a hotel. At dawn one of the girls called リゼ tries to wake others up but she herself falls back to sleep soon. Her friend シャロ notices that and says "あんなに起こすの張り切ってたのに…".
After the other girls get up, they notice that リゼ is the latest to get up. リゼ explains to them that it’s because シャロ didn’t wake her up. And シャロ says "こんな姿見たら起こすの悪いなーって".

The manga I am reading is ご注文はうさぎですか. I’d like to know if there is something omitted in the two sentences "あんなに起こすの張り切ってたのに…" and "こんな姿見たら起こすの悪いなーって"?

Should the complete versions be "あんなに起こすのが張り切ってたのに…" and "こんな姿見たら起こすのが悪いなーって"? Is the が omitted there? If not, how should I understand the phenomenon "verb+の+verb/adjective"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, something is omitted. I would say either を or に for the first and は or が for the second,